# How many threads can wait for lock?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, concurrency, locking

I have a PLSQL API which can be called from multiple threads concurrently. However, there is a piece of code in the API which I want to be accessed only by one thread at a time. I am using dbms_lock.request to handle concurrency and using following query for checking the number of threads that are waiting on lock:

```
SELECT
   l.*,
   substr(a.name,1,41) name,
   substr(s.program,1,45) program,
   p.spid SPID,
   s.osuser,
   l.SID SID,
   s.process PID,
   s.TERMINAL,
   S.STATUS
FROM
   sys.dbms_lock_allocated a,
   v$lock l,
   v$session s,
   v$process p
WHERE
   a.lockid = l.id1 and
   l.type = 'UL' and
   l.sid = s.sid and
   p.addr = s.paddr;
```

I see around only 200 threads waiting on a lock but actually there are thousands of thread invoking the API.

I want to know what guides the max number of threads that can wait on lock? And what happens to other threads that are accessing the API.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit, but most likely you have hit a limit higher up in the stack.

For example, if I had a connection pool of (say) 100 sessions, then from the database perspective I would see:

- 1 session from the pool holding the lock
- 99 sessions from the pool waiting for the lock

but from upstream, I might also see another 500 app sessions waiting to get a slot from the (currently full) connection pool.

"Thousands of threads" is concerning from an app design perspective